# Stop image in tumblr theme from stretching to full size of post

Tags: css, image, tumblr, image-resizing, tumblr-themes

I'm using the free tumblr theme Salvia (https://www.tumblr.com/theme/40508) and it stretches images in text posts to the full width of the page. I would like the images to not stretch and stay the size it is.  I've tried editing PhotoURL in the theme, and also adding code like this:

```
img {
max-width: 200px;
height: auto;
}
```

and it doesn't seem to change anything.  I would very much appreciate any help!

This is the pastebin of the layout - https://pastebin.com/5VUYGV3T
I'm not sure if this is the code in there that is really affecting the layout -

```
.image_resized.post-height-auto #layout .post .photo img{height:auto; !Important}
```

And the body.css theme asset https://pastebin.com/xnSgSx0W

Comment: It's probably some css that is linked to a class name. Can you provide the relevant code and/or a link to your blog. That's better than posting the entire template in pastebin.

Comment: Here is the link to the blog: https://eyreguide.tumblr.com/  I'm not sure what relevant class name info to add.  Thank you!

Comment: Your suggested approach seems to work when I test it via Chrome's console by adding new CSS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBmZs.png

Comment: Thank you! That did work!  Wow, I think it was because I didn't put it right where <style> started.  Thank you so much!